# How to make a dynamic structure in C

Tags: c, struct, dynamic, union, mtp

For example if i have a structure like this :

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed))
{
  uint16_t    ObjectPropertyCode;
  uint16_t    DataType;
  uint8_t     GetSet;
  union
  {
    uint8_t     DefaultValue_u8 ;
    uint16_t    DefaultValue_u16 ;
    uint32_t    DefaultValue_u32 ;
  }DefValue  ;
  uint32_t    GroupCode;
  uint8_t     FormFlag;
}
MTP_ObjectPropDescTypeDef;
```

I need to have just one element in DefValue , depending on my DataType.
for example if my DataType is uint16 , so i will send my structure like this :

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed))
{
  uint16_t    ObjectPropertyCode;
  uint16_t    DataType;
  uint8_t     GetSet;
  uint16_t    DefaultValue_u16 ;
  uint32_t    GroupCode;
  uint8_t     FormFlag;
}
MTP_ObjectPropDescTypeDef;
```

Comment: As shown, `DefValue` will always be sized to hold `uint32_t` regardless what you assign it, but you will need to know what type is stored so you can accurately retrieve the last value stored there.

Comment: I (possibly mistakenly) thought the problem was packing the data tightly with a variable size member in the middle.

Comment: Yes, you're right @vmt , in the MTP specification (media transfer protocol) , this value can take different type, and the struct must be well defined , to be recognized by the host.

Comment: Well that doesn't still really tell the whole story, i.e. what does it mean for the host to recognize it? If by that you mean that the DefaultValue must be of varying size, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're suggesting cannot be done (well, reasonably anyway), unless you break your data layout into parts, or change the data layout so that your variable size type will sit at the end.

With that out of the way, we can get to the unreasonable part. You can (ab)use the preprocessor to effectively achieve this to a degree. (for example):

```
#define JOIN3(a, b, c) a##b##c
#define MYSTRUCT(n) \
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)) { \
        uint16_t ObjectPropertyCode; \
        uint16_t DataType; \
        uint8_t GetSet; \
        JOIN3(uint, n, _t) DefaultValue; \
        uint32_t GroupCode; \
        uint8_t FormFlag; \
    }

// ...

{
    MYSTRUCT(8) obj; // uint8_t DefaultValue
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(obj)); // 11

    MYSTRUCT(16) obj2; // uint16_t DefaultValue
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(obj2)); // 12

    MYSTRUCT(32) obj3; // uint32_t DefaultValue
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(obj3)); // 14
}
```

But, it achieves the similar effect as just having three different structs to begin with. Consider using alternative methods where applicable, i.e. breaking the struct to parts, having different ones, or just using a plain buffer.

Consider the approach below which would build a buffer from the data provided. For example:

```
void build_output_buffer(const MTP_ObjectPropDescTypeDef *def, uint8_t *out)
{
    size_t header_size = offsetof(MTP_ObjectPropDescTypeDef, DefValue);
    memcpy(out, def, header_size);
    out += header_size;
    switch (def->DataType) {
        // Copy the appropriate value, e.g.:
        case DataType_U32: { // For demonstration's sake
            memcpy(out, &def->DefValue, 4);
            out += 4;
        } break;
    }
    size_t footer_offset = offsetof(MTP_ObjectPropDescTypeDef, GroupCode);
    size_t footer_size = sizeof(MTP_ObjectPropDescTypeDef) - footer_offset;
    memcpy(out, (uint8_t*)def + footer_offset, footer_size);
}
```

And make sure the buffer passed in will be big enough to hold all the data. Alternatively allocate it inside the function and return it. Or just skip the buffer and send the data out with similar logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this answer can helps , but not exactly what i want , because in my example i only put 3 types (uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t), but really, it can takes more than 3, (int8_t, char[], uint64_t ,.... ). 
so i think it's not a good idea to make 8 struct for example.

Comment: Maybe if i could add more one type ( char[ ] or uint8_t [ ] with variable size ) so i will support only them. (i need this one beacause sometimes i have to store long string (name of the file ) )

Comment: Thanks @vmt, I inspired from your answer a solution for my problem.